# How to Configure SSL over Database in Spring?

Tags: ssl, jdbc, informix

I want to add SSL security in the Database layer. I am using Struts2.1.6, Spring 2.5, JBOSS 5.0 and Informix 11.5. Any idea how to do this?

I have researched through a lot on the internet but could not find any solution.

Please suggest!

Here is my datasource and entity manager beans which is working perfect without SSL:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"  
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">  
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />  
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">  
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">  
            <property name="database" value="INFORMIX" />  
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />  

        </bean>  
    </property>  
</bean>  

<bean id="dataSource"  
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">  
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver" />  
    <property name="url"  
        value="jdbc:informix-sqli://SERVER_NAME:9088/DB_NAME:INFORMIXSERVER=SERVER_NAME;DELIMIDENT=y;" />  
    <property name="username" value="username" />  
    <property name="password" value="password" />  
    <property name="minIdle" value="2" />  
</bean>  

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean" lazy-init="false">  
    <property name="targetObject" ref="dataSource" />  
    <property name="targetMethod" value="addConnectionProperty" />  
    <property name="arguments">  
    <list>  
    <value>characterEncoding</value>  
    <value>UTF-8</value>  
    </list>  
    </property>  
</bean>  

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate" scope="prototype">  
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />  
</bean>  


<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">  
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />  
</bean>  

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

---

Thankyou very much for your suggestion. So basically I need to set something like this in my applicationContext.xml, Please correct me if I am wrong:

```
<property name="username" value="username" />  
<property name="password" value="password" />
**<property name="sslConnection" value="true" />** 
<property name="minIdle" value="2" />
```

But how do I set the SSL certificate in java runtime. The link which you have provided is good but for some reason I am not able to follow. Please put your suggestion.

Comment: This is a problem to be solved by the JDBC driver and database, and has nothing to do with JBoss or Spring.

Answer (score 1):

Using SSL for the communication between an application and a database is something that has to be supported by the database server (and the JDBC driver).

According to [the documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v115/topic/com.ibm.jccids.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/doc/c0024688.htm?resultof=%22%73%73%6c%22%20), this is supported by [Informix Dynamic Server (IDS)](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/informix/ids/) since version 11.50.

> You can use SSL support in your Java applications if you use **IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ type 4** connectivity to DB2® for z/OS®  Version 9 or later, to DB2 Database for Linux®, UNIX®, and Windows® Version 9.1, Fix Pack 2 or later, or to **IBM Informix® Dynamic Server (IDS) Version 11.50 or later**.
>
> (...)
>
> To use SSL connections, you need to:
>
> - Configure connections to the data source to use SSL. ([link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v115/topic/com.ibm.jccids.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/doc/t0054065.htm))
> - Configure your Java Runtime Environment to use SSL. ([link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v115/topic/com.ibm.jccids.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/doc/t0054066.htm))

The documentation should help.

If you're using a version of IDS prior to 11.50, then I'm afraid you'll have to use SSH tunneling.